# How would you design this specific many to many relationship Mongodb Schema?(mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make database for fighters and fights.
Every fight has two fighters and some information about the fight itself.
Every fighter has records of fights and some personal information.
So I'd like to relate these two schema.
I made those schemas, but not sure if I am doing it correctly using Mongoose. Is this right way to do it?

Here is the schema for fighter.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var fighterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    nickName: String,
    height: {
        foot: Number,
        inch: Number
    },
    weightClass: String,
    reach: Number,
    stance: String,

    dob: Date,
    country: String,

    fights: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Fight"
        }


    ]

})



module.exports = mongoose.model("Fighter", fighterSchema);
```

And this is schema for fight.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");



var fightSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    fighters: [
       {
            fighter: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Fighter"
        },


        knockDown: Number,
        significantStrikeLanded: Number,
        significantStrikeThrow: Number,
        takeDowns: Number,
        takeDownAttempts: Number,
        submissionAttempts: Number,
        result: String
    },

    {
        fighter: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Fighter"
        },


        knockDown: Number,
        significantStrikeLanded: Number,
        significantStrikeThrow: Number,
        takeDowns: Number,
        takeDownAttempts: Number,
        submissionAttempts: Number,
        result: String
    }


    ],


info : {

        noContest: Boolean,
        weightClass: String,
        method: String,
        round: Number,
        min: Number,
        sec: Number,
        timeFormat: {
            rounds: Number,
            min: Number,
        },

        referee: String,
        details: String,
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        eventCategory: String,


    }




})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Fight", fightSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the mongodb documentation on relations you will find that at mongodb they stated unless it is really important and there is huge amount of redundancy you can simply embed one of the dependent document within another.

in your case, each fight has only two fighters so you can simply embed the fighter's details within the fight document

```
fight{
...
fighters:{fighter 1}, {fighter 2}

}
```

and this is not bad at all.

or the other simple approach would be to drop the reference of fighters in fight schema and simply maintain a one to many relation between fighter and fights.

Comment: How would you store the information for each fighter? If it's one to many than I'll have to store fight information for one fighter and store the same fight information for the other fighter(opponent)? That;s redundunt. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

the comment section is small so putting it here instead : -

ok let me put an example and see if this makes sense.

fighters collection

```
{
_id: fighter1, 
name: xxxx, 
age: 22, 
skills :[a, b,c], 
fightsParticipated:[fight1, fight3, fight10....]},
{
_id: fighter2, 
name: yyyy, 
age: 25, 
skills :[ b,c,d], 
fightsParticipated:[fight4, fight7, fight10....]
} ,
{.................}
```

fights collection:

```
{
_id: fight10,
knockDown: Number,
        significantStrikeLanded: Number,
        significantStrikeThrow: Number,
        takeDowns: Number,
        takeDownAttempts: Number,
        submissionAttempts: Number,
        result: String
}
```

now from the above example we can see that fighter 1 participated in fight1, fight3 and fight 10 and fighter 2 in fight4, fight7 and fight 10. So both fighter fought with each other in fight 10.

the only redundent data here is the fight id's that you are storing for each fighter and that is not too much redundancy.

also in this case fight 10 can be part of only two fighters say if you has another 5 fighters in your collection fight 10 will bot be in their fight's participated list because a fight will be between only two fighters.

let me know if this makes sense.